# Date Formatting gives null

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsdateformatter

I have string "24 Jan 2012 09:21:21 +0000" and I want to make it a NSDate object as

```
NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterFullStyle];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZ"];
NSDate* date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateStr];

NSLog(@"%@",date);
```

gives me (null)

What i should do to get date in the format I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have a specific date format, you can set your formatter up to match it.

```
dateString = @"24 Jan 2012 09:21:21 +0000";
[formatter setDateFormat:@"d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"];
date = [formatter dateFromString:dateString];
NSLog(@"Date: %@", date);
```

You can see the list of date specifiers [here](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-10.html#Date_Format_Patterns).

Answer (score 1):

24 Jan 2012 09:21:21 +0000

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss ZZZ"];
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an obj C environment to verify, but your date string is "year month day" and the input you want to handle is "day (short)month year"